# Meaning of the "-o-rama" suffix

Tags: meaning

What is the origin of the "-o-rama" suffix (such as in "app-o-rama" [referenced](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB118255545661145353) by the Wall Street Journal), and how can this suffix be clearly defined?

Comment: -rama :
noun suffix meaning "sight, view, spectacular display or instance of," 1824, abstracted from panorama (q.v.), ultimately from Greek horama "sight, spectacle, that which is seen." (Etymonline)

Comment: also see "-apalooza"